# static in a non-static constructor

Tags: c#

I was unable to understand this part of code please help.

When i do this

```
public class TestClass
{
    static TestClass(int i)
    {
    }

    TestClass()
        : this(1)   // Error
    {
    }
}
```

it gives me error as

**'TestApp.TestClass' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments**

But when i do this, it does not show any error.

```
public class TestClass
{
    TestClass(int i)
    {
    }

    static TestClass()
        : this(1)
    {
    }
}
```

Some one please explain this behavior ?

Comment: Static constructors cannot specify arguments.

Comment: @DanielA.White while that's true, it's still strange that it would allow you to call the instance constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771890/why-a-static-constructors-do-not-have-any-parameters

Comment: Your second one doesn't compile either.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich It would be strange if it allowed it, but it doesn't allow it, as I would expect.

Comment: @Sevy I agree, could you provide what version of .net this worked on?

Comment: *'TestClass.TestClass()': static constructor cannot have an explicit 'this' or 'base' constructor call*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two errors in your first code:

1. You can't define `static` constructor with arguments.
2. You can't call `static` constructor. It is called by the framework for you before the class is used for the first time (but you cannot say exactly when).

Read more about static constructors on MSDN: [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Comment: Further reading about static constructors from the venerable Eric Lippert: http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/